# I need to know what exactly this will do: (grep & xargs)

Tags: bash, grep, xargs

Here is the line:

```
find /localdir/ | grep '[0-9']$ | xargs -i% cp % /tftpboot
```

I specifically want to know what grep is looking for exactly here.
Can anyone translate it for me please ?

I am also kind of interested in what the xargs cmd is going to look like...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you investigate (search) for yourself?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) output from your code and all **relevant** error messages exactly as they appear. Also, make sure to include some samples of what you're testing against.

Comment: did you copy/paste that statement?  bc the grep looks wrong.  it looks like one of the single quotes is out of place.  i'm thinking it should be `grep '[0-9]$'`, which would make Eevee's answer below correct.

Comment: Yes - I think you are right - I will adjust it and check the results - it was the placement of the single quote that confused me - and led me to ask this question here...  Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[0-9]` means any character from `0` through `9`.  `$` means the end of a line.  So your `grep` will find any line (i.e., filename) that ends with a digit, and `xargs` will copy them each to `/tftpboot`.

Of course, you'll have some surprises if any of those filenames contain spaces.  You can do this entirely within the shell in zsh (and I *think* in recent versions of bash):

```
cp /localdir/**/*[0-9] /tftpboot
```

---

addendum: If you're asking about the funny quoting, that *will* work, though it's not very human-friendly.

The key is that you can have quoted strings and non-quoted strings right next to each other in shell, and they'll become a single string; `echo "fo"ob'ar'` will produce `foobar`.

The first part is quoted because `[` is special to bash.  `]` is also special, but since bash never saw a special (unquoted) `[`, it leaves the `]` alone.  `$` would normally substitute a variable, but nothing comes after it, so bash leaves that alone too.

The string that actually gets passed to grep is still `[0-9]$`.

Comment: +1 for the explanation of why it works despite the quoting error.  i would never have expected it to work as written.